# Dimension of a tangent space of the normalization of a domain

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a finitely generated (commutative) domain over an algebraically
closed field $k.$ Let $B$ be the normalization of $A$. Let $m$ be a maximal
ideal in $A$, and $m'$ be a maximal ideal in $B$ lying over $m.$
Then is it true that $dim_{k}(m/m^2)\geq dim_{k}(m'/m'^2)$?

Comment: No. Let $A=k[x^4, x^3y, xy^3, y^4]$. Its normalization is $A[x^2y^2]$. With $m,m'$ the obvious maximal ideals, $\dim (m/m^2)=4,\dim (m'/m'^2)=5$.

Comment: That works, thanks!